# Discord.py | Adding Img/icons to Disocrd Embed

Tags: python

Im trying to make a discord bot for league of legends like BaronBot So the idea is that i want the bot To parse Some Data **scraped** from op.gg  using discord Embed But i don't know How to make Images from urls visible in discord embed fields To explain more here is an example of the output that i want [image: Picture from BaronBot]

But here is the output im getting
[image]

My code :

embed.add_field(name = f"Player : name" , value =f"{ChampImageUrl}")

await ctx.send(embed = embed)

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody needs this information,
In order to use "imgs" within embed in Discord.py, Discord requires them to be as emojis.

You can get the emoji format by doing

\:{emoji_name}:   in a discord chat, or channel

once you got that, just copy and paste it where you wanted to be, as part of the string.

Here you can find the info on how to get the format:

https://docs.discordbotstudio.org/misc/how-to-use-custom-emojis